# Phonegap Build Start Page

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap

I am currently working on a PhoneGap Build App and can't seem to find a way of forcing the app to start from the index.html page every time. For example, if the app is suspended and opened again it will naturally open to the last page the user was viewing. However, I would like to force the app to go to the index.html page after being suspended or any time the app is opened.

Does anyone know how this could be completed?

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the [resume event](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#resume) and do your navigation in the callback. Quoting from the docs:

> The resume event fires when the native platform pulls the application
>   out from the background.

A simple code example could look like this:

```
document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);

function onResume() {
    // navigate to index.html
}
```